# How to name elements in a razor table to submit via JQuery/JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC page I have a table with a number of elements I would like to use with an Ajax call. The MVC controller action I would like to call to is defined like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult _submissionSort(List<SubmissionSortViewModel> recordsToSort)
```

(`SubmissionSortViewModel` is a class with only 3 properties, `ProjectSubmissionId`, `ProjectId`, and `ChapterNumber`.)

I'm defining the table in markup like this:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ProjectSubmissions.Count; i++) //each (var item in Model.ProjectSubmissions)//
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.ProjectSubmissions[i].ProjectSubmissionId, 
                new { @name = "recordsToSort[" + i + "].ProjectSubmissionId" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.ProjectSubmissions[i].ProjectId, 
                new { @name = "recordsToSort[" + i + "].ProjectId" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.ProjectSubmissions[i].ChapterNumber, 
                new { @name = "recordsToSort[" + i + "].ChapterNumber", @class = "SortOrder" })
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ProjectSubmissions[i].ProjectTitle)
        </td>
```

My ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(".sortable-table").attr("data-source-href"),
    type: "POST",
    data: $(".sortable-table :input").serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        ClearAndRefresh(); 
    },
    error: function (data) {
        debugger;
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

The elements get rendered like this:

```
<input data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="The ProjectSubmissionId field is required."
    id="ProjectSubmissions_1__ProjectSubmissionId"
    name="ProjectSubmissions[1].ProjectSubmissionId" 
    type="hidden" value="8ee0db23-f7d4-e511-8c3c-00215e466552">
```

So, when the controller gets the call, it doesn't recognize the object. I could possibly redefine the action like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult _submissionSort(List<SubmissionSortViewModel> ProjectSubmissions)
```

But I'd really like to keep the method parameter lowercase.

How do I get my hidden elements to have the name I want, `recordsToSort[0].ProjectSubmissionId`?

Comment: i think your hiddens should be `model => model.` not `modelItem => Model` (notice the lower case 'm')

Comment: I have no idea why you have accepted that answer. It is just plain wrong! The model is your view contains a property which is typeof `List<SubmissionSortViewModel>`, but your method parameter is not the same model - its just the property of the model. Make your parameter the same as the model in the view (or you can use the `[Bind(Prefix = "ProjectSubmissions")]` attribute) and everything will bound correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ordinary `Hidden` instead of `HiddenFor` in your case:

```
@Html.Hidden("YourProperty", Model.ProjectSubmissions[i].ProjectSubmissionId
, new { 
   @id = "recordsToSort_" + i + "_ProjectSubmissionId"
   , @name = "recordsToSort[" + i + "].ProjectSubmissionId" 
})
```